# How to integrate SPP profile in Android Application?

Tags: android, bluetooth, spp

I am trying to develop an application which communicates with an embedded device that is working on spp profile. The current app that I have written makes the mobile device discoverable but when I select the pairing option on the embedded device, it tells pairing failed.

So how can I make my application to start a connection with that device i.e, how can I integrate spp profile in my application?
Please help on this issue...